# Problem using vcpkg in Visual Studio (msbuild) with a project built as x86 & x64

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2022, vcpkg

I am new to vcpkg and currently facing an issue when building a project that requires to be build as x86 & x64. Maybe I am just missing something or haven't understood how it is intended to work:
The issue is that building the project fails for x86 after having it build once for x86 followed by x64.

We have the `vcpkg.json` and the `vcpkg-configuration.json` in the project root and use this settings in Visual Studio:

[image]

The problem can be reproduced as follows:
When first building the project from Visual Studio as `Win32`, vcpkg builds the x86 dependency libraries. The build succeeds.
Now the vcpkg `installed` directory looks like this:

[image]

Building the x64 version afterwards also succeeds but deletes the `x86-windows` folder in the `installed` directory.
Subsequent builds of the x86 version are then failing (deleting the `.msbuildstamp-x86-windows.stamp` makes it "work" again as the dependencies are then build again).

[image]

I wouldn't have expected this behavior, especially not because the `.msbuildstamp-x86-windows.stamp` is not deleted.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues) to ask for a fix or workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the position of the `<VcpkgEnableManifest>true</VcpkgEnableManifest>` inside the .vcproj file. Although Visual Studio (in our case 2022) shows `Use Vcpkg Manifest` as `Yes` in the UI, it is not treated as enabled by vcpkg itself.
Moving `<VcpkgEnableManifest>true</VcpkgEnableManifest>` up inside the .vcproj file solves the issue and correctly enabled manifest mode; see [VCPKG issue #27106](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/27106).

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider adding an answer and changing its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :) It will also help others to solve the similar issue.